# Selenium missing tags when using custom user-agent string

Tags: python, selenium, tags, user-agent

Selenium (in Python) with Firefox fails to find tags when custom user_agent is used.

Building a python based google scraper to collect the first page of url's generated from a google query. Selenium is used to open the page and enter the query. find_element_by_tag_name('a') then applied to find target elements containing urls.

For example, if the query searched for is "facebook.com" i'm looking for elements like the following" e.g

`<a href="/url?q=https://www.facebook............ </a>`

Works perfectly on default user string:

`Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.14; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0`

Fails to find all tags for custom user string:

`Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); de; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5`

Note, the tag being searched for 'a' is common to all user-agents. The 'a' tags returned on failure are almost exclusively associated to google-specific links, e.g

`https://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/policies/terms/?fg=1`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

query = 'facebook'
user = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686 (x86_64); de; rv:1.9.1) Gecko/20090624 Firefox/3.5"

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("general.useragent.override", user)
options = Options()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, options=options)

browser.get('https://www.google.com')
search_bar = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
search_bar.send_keys(query)
search_bar.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(10)
print('\n Current url: ', self.browser.current_url) #check loaded
elements = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
print('Elements returned: ', len(elements))
url_list = [element.get_attribute("href") for element in elements]
```

Expect, for elements to contain url's linked to query

Result actual, element found all reference google

Comment: you have opened browser so open DevTools and see what you have in HTML for this user-agent. Some portals send different content for different devices - which are recognized by user-agent. For example Google sends different HTML when it see that browser doesn't run JavaScript.

Comment: your code works correctly with custom 'user-agent' on my computer. It gets 109 elements. But page looks different then in normal browser - it looks like page which doesn't use JavaScript. It works correctly even if I use only `"Mozilla/5.0"` as  `user-agent` but then it looks again like normal page. Linux Mint 19.2 / Python 3.7.4 / Selenium 3.141.0

Comment: BTW: if page sends HTML with `<iframe>` then you have to use `switch_to.frame(..)` to get `<a>` which are in `<iframe>`

Comment: Ah, it seems to be that all the url's are being captured but with an additional google search string in front. e.g for the url:
<a href="/url q=https://www.kcl.ac.uk..... </a>
the program, for some types for user_agent returns:
https://www.google.com/url?q=https://www.kcl.ac.uk

As to the iframe, thanks for the heads-up & for testing out the code!